There is exactly one nontrivial line bundle over $S^1,$ up to equivalence. Its total space is diffeomorphic to a Möbius strip.
I am currently studying for a manifolds course and have come across the following exercise:

Exercise: There is exactly one nontrivial line bundle over $S^1,$ up to equivalence. Its total space is diffeomorphic to a Möbius strip. Construct it.

I do not know how to proceed. I know that the normal bundle of $S^1$ is trivial but I do not have any idea how to go about constructing another line bundle over $S^1$.

Note: constructing the bundle is straightforward since you know what it is (it may be easier to consider $S^1$ as $[0, 1]/\sim$, where the endpoints are identified). The more subtle part is to show that up to bundle isomorphism, that these are the only two possibilities.

Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

@psl2Z Sorry, what additional context do you need here?

@AdilRaza For instance what you've tried so far, what you've thought about, etc. Also, please tell us what general level of theory you have access to: With, say, knowledge about what space represents $\mathrm{Vect}_1$ this is basically trivial.

Have you started by writing down what the Möbius strip is and understanding that you can interpret it as (diffeomorphic to) a line bundle on the circle?
